# How to Add items to React Native AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm building an application where user inserts a task and the time at which the task was created and both are saved into asyncStorage in react native. When a new task is added to the asyncstorage,i expected both the previous task and the new task to be displayed by the `getItems()` function.
How can it be done?

```
async function saveItems() {
      const items = []
              items.push(task,timestamp )
              await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(items))
          }

     async function getItems() {
          try {
            const items =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
            if (items !== null) {
              console.log(JSON.parse(items));
            }      
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function saveItems() { 
   var items = AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
   if(items)
       items.push([task,timestamp] ) 
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', items);
 } 

async function getItems() { 
         const items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
         if (items !== null)
         console.log(items);
}
```

Items will be array of arrays
Ex :

```
items = [[task1,timestamp1],[task2,timestamp2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is define a structure for a task like

```
const task = {
  description: '',
  timestamp: ''
}
```

Now whenever a task is created you can append it into the tasks which are stored in AsyncStorage.

```
const saveItems = async() => {
  const tasks = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
  if(tasks != null){
    const updatedTasks = JSON.parse(tasks).append(task);
    await asyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(updatedTasks))
  }
  else{
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify([task]))
  }
}
```

Now when you will get the items from AsyncStrorage it will retrieve the complete list of tasks